# Generate a custom tzdb.dat for Java time zones

Tags: java, timezone

With Java 1.6 I generated a jre/lib/zi/America/Sao_Paulo time zone file from a .zic file, which has a content like following:

```
Rule Brazil 2012 only - Feb 26 06:00 0 S
Rule Brazil 2012 only - Oct 21 00:00 1 D
Rule Brazil 2013 only - Feb 17 06:00 0 S
Rule Brazil 2013 only - Oct 20 00:00 1 D
Rule Brazil 2014 only - Feb 16 06:00 0 S
Rule Brazil 2014 only - Oct 19 00:00 1 D
Rule Brazil 2015 only - Feb 22 06:00 0 S
Rule Brazil 2015 only - Oct 18 00:00 1 D
Rule Brazil 2016 only - Feb 21 06:00 0 S
Rule Brazil 2016 only - Oct 16 00:00 1 D
Rule Brazil 2017 only - Feb 19 06:00 0 S
Rule Brazil 2017 only - Oct 15 00:00 1 D
Zone Brazil/East -3:00 Brazil BR%sT
```

Now, with Java 8, the jre/lib/zi folder no longer exists. It was replaced by the jre/lib/tzdb.dat file.

How can I generate this tzdb.dat file with my custom Time Zones?

Comment: Is there reason why you've moved all of the fall-back transitions to 6:00 AM?  If not, the built-in `America/Sao_Paulo` zone would be more appropriate.

Comment: Matt, the America/Sao_Paulo zone doesn't fit my business need.

Comment: Just my opinion, but the business needs of an application should be reflected in the application code - not in a custom time zone.  The time zones are meant to reflect the real local time of a physical location.  If your code needs a custom time zone to calculate time for your business need, then there's something wrong with your code.

Comment: Besides, this custom rule set is a bit unbalanced.  Say for example you were paying employees based on the local time output of these rules, and these employees worked overnight until 5am.  Well, in February you've moved the fall-back transition so you don't pay them an extra hour, but in October you left the spring-forward transition alone, so you'll underpay by an hour.   The better thing to do is to *always* calculate the real elapsed time worked, by recording either UTC, or local date+time+offset values.

Comment: I agree with you, but that decision wasn't taken by me and there's no time to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.

- Download a Time Zone Database from the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (iana - http://www.iana.org/time-zones). In my case, Time Zone Data v. 2015f (http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/releases/tzdata2015f.tar.gz)
- Unpack the compressed file.
- Edit the file which references the location. In my case, southamerica.
- Replace the lines with custom values.

  Rule Brazil 2012 only - Feb 26 06:00 0 S
  Rule Brazil 2012 only - Oct 21 00:00 1 D
- Repack the files into a tar.gz file.
- Calculate the sha512 hash for the file (https://defuse.ca/checksums.htm#checksums)
- Create a file containing the sha512 hash.
- Name this file with the same name of the tar.gz adding .sha512 at the end of the name.
- Put both files in the same directory
- Use the Timezone Updater Tool (tzupdater.jar) - http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/tzupdater-readme-136440.html - for create a new tzdb.dat file

  java -jar tzupdater.jar -f -l file:///path/to/file/tzdata2015f.tar.gz

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to try this backport-class:

[TzdbZoneRulesCompiler](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/bp/zone/TzdbZoneRulesCompiler.java)

But note: It is **not public** (you could circumvent it by copy-and-paste or similar) hence not really intended for public usage. And furthermore, it is not the original tz compiler used by oracle but probably creates the same output (assuming that this detail was kept identical in backport of java.time).

And I agree with the comments of Matt Johnson to avoid using custom time zones if possible and to adjust the application code instead. You could also consider creating custom time zones by defining specialized [zone rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#of-java.time.ZoneOffset-java.time.ZoneOffset-java.util.List-java.util.List-java.util.List-) (via the official Java-8-API).